# Format JSON Output

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I am passing a WordPress custom post type as a JSON feed to my app.

I created a JSON page template which queries and displays the results as below:

```
$directories [] = array(
'subtype' => 'mcms',
'type' => 'maps', 
'summary' => get_the_title(),
'title' => get_the_title(),
'address' => get_field('address'),
'content' => get_the_content(),
'author' => get_the_author()
  );
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo json_encode ($directories);
```

The output from this is:

```
[
{
"subtype": "mcms",
"type": "maps",
"summary": "Directory Listing",
"title": "Directory Listing",
"address": false,
"content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
"author": "admin"
}
]
```

I would like to format the output as follows:

```
"items:" [
{
"subtype": "mcms",
"type": "maps",
"summary": "Directory Listing",
"title": "Directory Listing",
"address": false,
"content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
"author": "admin"
}
]
```

I am trying the following:

```
 echo  "items: ", json_encode ($directories);
```

But the output isn't JSON formatted which I need

Any help?

Comment: Did you try putting quotes around `items:` in the string?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `$directories` in an array before you call `json_encode`.

```
$items = ['items' => $directories];

echo json_encode($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the directories in an array is the solution:

echo json_encode (array('items' => $directories));

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$directories[] = array(...
```

To this

```
$directories['items'][] = array(...
```

And your echo leave it as this

```
echo json_encode($directories);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could get your output to be like this:

```
[
    {
        "items:" [
            {
                "subtype": "mcms",
                "type": "maps",
                "summary": "Directory Listing",
                "title": "Directory Listing",
                "address": false,
                "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                "author": "admin"
            }
        ]
     }
]
```

you need to create an Object for the items, and then create a hashmap

```
Map<String, List<KeyValue>> map = new HashMap();
map.put("items", itemObject);
JsonBuilderFactory jsnFactory = Json.createBuilderFactory(null);
JsonObjectBuilder builder = jsnFactory.createObjectBuilder();
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    builder.add(keu,map.get(key));
}
return builder.build().toString();
```

return